# Angular 5 custom pagination with Laravel 5

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5, angular5

I wants to create a custom pagination in Angular 5 which is supporting by Laravel 5 as back end. My intention is if there is 7 pages then the pagination will look like : 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5; if users click on the 3, the pagination will look like 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 etc. To achieve this, I have created a custom pagination in my product.component.ts as follows:

```
 createRange(number, current_page){
    console.log('current page='+current_page);

    var items: number[] = [];
    for(var i = current_page; i <= current_page + 2; i++){
       items.push(i);
    }
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
    return items;
  }


directPage(url, pathNo) { //console.log(url);
  var link_path = url+"?page="+pathNo;
  this.productService.getURLpage(link_path).subscribe(data => {
        this.products = data.products.data;
        this.products_paging = data.products;

        });
  }
```

In product.component.html, I have the following code:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="createRange(5, products_paging.current_page)" let-currentElementIndex="index+1">
  <button (click)="directPage(products_paging.path, currentElementIndex)">{{currentElementIndex}}</button>
</ng-template>
```

The pagination is working /changing data based on the buttons in the pagination I selected however, the pagination numbers are not changing itself like it keep the buttons like 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5. My question is - how can I change the pagination buttons (numbers) if I select any number from there? Let me know if this clears, otherwise I will update my question for more clear.

Below is the jSON which laravel returns to me:

```
{
    "products": {
        "current_page": 2,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "product_name": "Patrick Stoltenberg",
                "description": "Dinah, tell me the truth: did you call him Tortoise--' 'Why did they live on?' said Alice, who felt ready to ask help of any one; so, when the White Rabbit. She was looking up into the air off all.",
                "rating": 8,
                "price": 13.5,
                "uploaded_image": "",
                "created_at": "2018-03-22 05:34:39",
                "updated_at": "2018-03-22 05:34:39"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "product_name": "Micheal Davis",
                "description": "Has lasted the rest of my own. I'm a deal faster than it does.' 'Which would NOT be an advantage,' said Alice, 'a great girl like you,' (she might well say this), 'to go on crying in this way! Stop.",
                "rating": 3,
                "price": 27.6,
                "uploaded_image": "",
                "created_at": "2018-03-22 05:34:39",
                "updated_at": "2018-03-22 05:34:39"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "product_name": "Minnie Ebert",
                "description": "Mouse had changed his mind, and was going to leave off being arches to do it?' 'In my youth,' Father William replied to his son, 'I feared it might injure the brain; But, now that I'm perfectly sure.",
                "rating": 0,
                "price": 40.9,
                "uploaded_image": "",
                "created_at": "2018-03-22 05:34:39",
                "updated_at": "2018-03-22 05:34:39"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "product_name": "Noble Jerde1",
                "description": "He looked at the top of its right ear and left off quarrelling with the bones and the beak-- Pray how did you do either!' And the executioner ran wildly up and beg for its dinner, and all the party.",
                "rating": 14,
                "price": 25,
                "uploaded_image": "",
                "created_at": "2018-03-22 05:34:39",
                "updated_at": "2018-04-04 07:23:13"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "product_name": "Flo Connelly",
                "description": "INSIDE, you might do something better with the lobsters to the other, and making faces at him as he came, 'Oh! the Duchess, who seemed to her feet in a natural way again. 'I wonder if I've kept her.",
                "rating": 9,
                "price": 40.8,
                "uploaded_image": "",
                "created_at": "2018-03-22 05:34:39",
                "updated_at": "2018-03-22 05:34:39"
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/product?page=1",
        "from": 6,
        "last_page": 3,
        "last_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/product?page=3",
        "next_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/product?page=3",
        "path": "http://localhost:8000/api/product",
        "per_page": 5,
        "prev_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/product?page=1",
        "to": 10,
        "total": 15
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your code in stackblitz ?

Comment: @dgpoo - stackblitz is time taking as I don't know anything here. Should I update my question with the jSON values which Laravel provided me?

Comment: yes please please share it

Comment: @dgpoo - question updated.

Comment: have you checked createRange() function is calling or not?

Comment: @dgpoo Yes, createRange function called. Because the Pagination is working as I select the 1 or 2 or 3 etc. However, My intention is when I select e.g. 4 , the pagination buttons will change automatically like 4 | 5 | 6 etc. That means full control so that I can change my decision which numbers I need to display there.

Comment: @dgpoo - Any update on this?

Comment: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/angular-2-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google

http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/advanced
  
please check above link may be helpfult to you

Comment: @dgpoo - I have implemented ngx pagination in my project. It shows the correct page numbers and styles which I'm expecting much. However, clicking on the page numbers fro pagination, the items are not changing. Because, it won't call the server side API which is made in laravel 5. Do you have any idea how to call server side API in ngx pagination by clicking on numbers?

Comment: I have shared code of server side pagination

Comment: Is this example in ngx pagination, Or custom?

Comment: it is ngx pagination example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169303/discussion-between-dgpoo-and-niladri-banerjee-uttarpara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Html Code:**

```
<ul class="meal-list">
<li *ngFor="let meal of asyncMeals | async | paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: total }">
    {{ meal }}
</li>
</ul>
<div class="has-text-centered">
 <div class="spinner" [ngClass]="{ 'hidden': !loading }"></div>
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="getPage($event)" id="server">
  </pagination-controls>
```

**Typescript Code:**

```
    import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input} from "@angular/core";
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

    interface IServerResponse {
        items: string[];
        total: number;
    }

    @Component({
        selector: 'server-example',
        templateUrl: './server-example.component.html',
        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
    export class ServerExampleComponent {

        @Input('data') meals: string[] = [];
        asyncMeals: Observable<string[]>;
        p: number = 1;
        total: number;
        loading: boolean;

        ngOnInit() {
            this.getPage(1);
        }

        getPage(page: number) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.asyncMeals = serverCall(this.meals, page)
                .do(res => {
                    this.total = res.total;
                    this.p = page;
                    this.loading = false;
                })
                .map(res => res.items);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Simulate an async HTTP call with a delayed observable.
     */
    function serverCall(meals: string[], page: number): Observable<IServerResponse> {
        const perPage = 10;
        const start = (page - 1) * perPage;
        const end = start + perPage;

        return Observable
            .of({
                items: meals.slice(start, end),
                total: 100
            }).delay(1000);
    }
```